# UIWebView action sheet popup on a link - customization

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uimenucontroller

I'm trying to replace or add more options into the action sheet popup in uiwebview. When touching long touch on a link standard uiwebview popup shows up. I saw some apps which did it, but i can't figure it out.

the standard options are : open or copy, i want to hide copy and add send email.

Any help ?

Thanks
Albert

Answer (score 2):

That "action" popup can be disabled in a `UIWebView` by setting the CSS class `-webkit-touch-callout: none` or by setting `document.documentElement.style.webkitTouchCallout = "none";` in javascript.

Once you disable the default behavior you can create any custom action sheet you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

You want to customize the UIMenuItems of the UIMenuController.  I explain how to do this  here:  [Customize UIMenuController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604716/customize-uimenucontroller/4079896#4079896)

Comment: I don't think that is what he's asking. He's looking to change the UIActionSheet not the UIMenuController. Different things.

Comment: gotcha.  I never knew about "long press" on a link!