# Trouble Displaying UIMenuController When Cell Tapped In UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uimenucontroller

I'm trying to display a custom UIMenuController when a User long presses on a cell in a grouped UITableView. However, I can't seem to get the UIMenuController to display after successfully detecting the long press. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
MyViewController.h
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
  UITableView *table;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *table;
@end
```

In the cellForRowAtIndexPath I attach my Long Press Gesture Recognizer

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:SectionsTableIdentifier] autorelease];
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
    [longPress release];
```

Here is my handleLongPress action method

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UIGestureRecognizer *)longPress {

  if (longPress.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

    CGPoint pressLocation = [longPress locationInView:self.table];
    NSIndexPath *pressedIndexPath = [self.table indexPathForRowAtPoint:pressLocation];

    UIMenuItem *first = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" action:@selector(saveRecent)];
    UIMenuItem *second = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" action:@selector(editQuery)];

    UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    menuController.menuItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:first,second,nil];

    [menuController setTargetRect:longPress.view.frame inView:longPress.view.superview];
    [menuController setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
    [pressedIndexPath release];
  }
}
```

The Action methods for the Edit and Save just display a UIAlertView. I also implemented the below method to ensure that when the UIMenuController is displayed only Save and Edit options will be present

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {

 BOOL canPerform = NO;

 if (action == @selector(saveRecent)) {
    canPerform = YES;
 }
 if (action == @selector(editQuery)) {
    canPerform = YES;
 }

 return canPerform;
}
```

I'm also claiming MyViewController to be first responder

```
-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {

  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to have a view claiming firstResponder status in order to present the UIMenuController.  I don't see that happening in your code.

I wrote up directions for using the UIMenuController as an answer to this question:

[Customize UIMenuController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604716/customize-uimenucontroller/4079896#4079896)

Comment: I do have that. In the implementation file of MyViewController -(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {

 return YES;
}

Comment: But you need to need to call [someView becomeFirstResponder] to become first responder.

Comment: The UIMenuController uses the firstResponder view as the starting point to send messages to.  If there isn't a first responder active, then it wont show the menu.  The view to which your menu applies needs to be made the first responder by calling becomeFirstResponder.

Comment: Yep, I had forgotten to handle that in the handleLongGesture method. Thanks for your help and reference guide.

Comment: Based on the code above do you see any reason why the MenuController that is displayed is placed near the middle of the view and not where the longpress occurred?

Comment: Placement is determined by the view that has firstResponder status.  It has nothing to do with any touch events that may have occurred.  But you can provide a rectangle area that the menu applies to.  See - (void)setTargetRect:(CGRect)targetRect inView:(UIView *)targetView