# ios 7 - Custom UIMenuItem not working on TableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uimenucontroller

I am working on adding custom `UIMenuItem` on tableViewCell. I used this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290828/how-to-show-a-custom-uimenuitem-for-a-uitableviewcell) to to add customMenuItem. This worked fine on ios 6. But it is not at all working on ios 7.

Below is the implementation I have:

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIMenuItem *sendByEmailMenuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Send By Email" action:@selector(sendByEmail:)];
[[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuItems: @[sendByEmailMenuItem]];
[[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] update];
```

Then adding its delegate

```
// Shared Menu item delegate actions

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.orderAtIndex = [self.orders objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canPerformAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender 
{
    return  (action == @selector(sendByEmail:));
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView performAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender {
    if (action == @selector(sendByEmail:)) {
        [self sendByEmail:sender];
    }
}
```

// Subclassing Table View cells

```
-(BOOL) canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    return (action == @selector(sendByEmail:));
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

- (void) sendByEmail: (id) sender {
    // Some actions...
}
```

What I am doing wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: lol I banged my head with this 3 days ago… :) but now i got it working

Comment: What was the issue. Can you please add you solution

Comment: Yup the issue was the method wasn't been called… the `becomeFirstResponder` method did the trick… Code is provided in answer..

Comment: helped u solve it...?

Comment: No, I added it in my TableViewController implementation. But not working

Comment: Menu item is not appearing. Call to `canPerformAction` is not hitting

Comment: try these links… [question1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473959/uimenucontroller-with-uitableviewcontroller-doesnt-work) [question2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258839/trouble-displaying-uimenucontroller-when-cell-tapped-in-uitableview)

Answer (score 1):

In `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad` , i added these

```
 UIMenuItem *translateToMenu = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Translate to.." action:@selector(translateTo:)];
 UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
 [menuController setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:translateToMenu]];
 [menuController setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
```

added this method

```
-(void) translateTo: (id) sender {}
```

and add only these 2 methods

```
- (BOOL) canPerformAction:(SEL)selector withSender:(id) sender {
    if (selector == @selector(translateTo:)) 
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}

- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
```

Try this and let me know…

Comment: Thanks, I added this to fresh project with tableViewController. But still not working. Does it really worked for you?

Comment: yes i have it working here… is it showing or is it not even showing?

Comment: one more thing u have to add… `[self becomeFirstResponder];` did u add this ?

Comment: You didn't add any table view delegate actions for this. Like I have above? I tried them y keeping and removing too. But can not get it working

Comment: ohh.. one thing do u have custom tableViewCell ?

Comment: No, I have Normal prototype cell

Comment: ohm then in any place do u `setUserInteractionEnabled` to `false`?

Comment: Sorry, I have used normal protype cell, which is used to create a dynmic cells runtime. No i am `setUserInteractionEnabled ` to false any where

Comment: one thing u can do is attach a `UILongPressGesture` to it… and on its method call uimenucontroller…