# shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath and Copy menu position

Tags: ios, tableview, uimenucontroller

I need to copy some text from an UITableView.
I'm using the method shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath, it does work perfectly ! But, I'd like to set the position (on the x axis, horizontally) of the "Copy" menu item. How to do it ?

Thank you for ur help !

Sincerely,

Hervé D.

Answer (score -1):

You're better off with a custom `UILongPressGEstureRecognizer` and handling the `UIMenuController` yourself.

Check point 4) of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4079896/1049134).